# how to access variables in main.php into another php file

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm very new to php web development with yii2 framework. I am working on a web application and I have few variables in my return of main.php file (config folder).

```
return [
    'components' => [            
        'authClientCollection' => [
            'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
            'clients' => [
                'facebook' => [
                   //some fields
                ],
                'google' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\GoogleOAuth',
                    'clientId' => 'somerandomnumber.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                    'clientSecret' => '6f7g8h9i10j',
                ],
            ],
        ],
]
```

I have to use `google's clientId` in Model folder's php file.

```
<a href="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2FCURRENT-DOMAIN%2Fgoogle%2Dlogin&response_type=permission&scope=email+profile+openid&client_id=GET THE CLIENT ID HERE">
                <div class="gplus_seperator">
                    <div class="social_logo">
                        <span class="icon-font">p</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="social_text">Sign in with Google+</div>
                </div>
            </a>
```

Can some one help me. TIA

Comment: `Yii::$app->components['authClientCollection']['clients']['google']['clientId']`

Comment: @InsaneSkull thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access components using:

```
Yii::$app->components['authClientCollection']['clients']['go‌​ogle']['clientId'];
```